# Created an image gallery with Bootstrap Grid & Flexbox but the some images are not occupying 100% of the flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, bootstrap-5

I'm new to web development and I'm trying to create a responsive image gallery with Bootstrap Grid and flexbox but for some reason some of the images are not taking the full height of flex container.

[What it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqsfC.jpg)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.tile {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tile img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.tile img:hover {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                class="img-one"
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/02/22/20/bouquet-142876_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-two"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/02/23/03/mountains-190055_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-three"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/20/13/sunset-815270_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-four"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/01/22/19/44/flower-field-250016_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-five"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/rose-729509_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-six"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-seven"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-eight"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What should I do so that all images are of the same height, alternatively occupy full height of the flex container?

Answer (score 1):

Add `height:100%`on `a` tag

```
.tile a{
 height:100%;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.tile {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.tile a{
 height:100%;
}
.tile img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.tile img:hover {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                class="img-one"
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/02/22/20/bouquet-142876_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-two"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/02/23/03/mountains-190055_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-three"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/20/13/sunset-815270_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-four"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/01/22/19/44/flower-field-250016_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-five"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/rose-729509_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-six"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-seven"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-eight"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this and although height of all elements/images in the same row is same, it is different across rows, I mean in the full page window height of images in second row is different than height of images in first row.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add .tile .picture { height and width inherit } and you can add same for .tile img { height and width: inherit } it will work. I've also created demo for you.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.tile {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tile .picture {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.tile img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.tile img:hover {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                class="img-one"
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/02/22/20/bouquet-142876_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-two"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/02/23/03/mountains-190055_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-three"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/20/13/sunset-815270_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-four"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/01/22/19/44/flower-field-250016_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-five"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/rose-729509_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-six"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-seven"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-eight"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use just heigh 100% including 'a' tag with 'title' parent.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  position: relative;
}

body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.tile , a{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tile img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.tile img:hover {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                class="img-one"
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/02/22/20/bouquet-142876_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-two"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/02/23/03/mountains-190055_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-three"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/20/13/sunset-815270_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-four"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/01/22/19/44/flower-field-250016_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-five"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/rose-729509_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-six"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-seven"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 mb-4">
          <div class="tile">
            <a class="picture" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014_960_720.jpg"
                alt=""
                class="img-eight"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```